# Calculating earnings (intro javascript style)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

> Write the JavaScript to read the number of hours worked from the user. Then write the JavaScript to calculate how much money the user made if they were paid $12/hour for the first 40 hours worked, and $18/hr for all hours worked over 40. Then use console.log to print out the hours entered and the total amount made.

So that's the code I have to write.

I can get the first part no problem from 0-40. But I can't figure out how to have and if/else statement calculate the first 40 at $12/h and the remaining at $18/h.

my code right now looks like

```
let hours = Number(prompt("Numbers of hours worked"))
console.log("# of hours worked is " +hours) 
let regularHours = (hours >=40
if (hours <= 40) {
    console.log("In " +hours+ " you made $" +hours *12)
} else {
    console.log("In " +hours+ "you made $" +)
```

can I define a variable to be like

```
let regularHours = hours <=40 *12

let overtimeHours = hours >40 *18
```

I tried that but it doesn't quite work.

Am I over complicating this?

Comment: if(hours>40) then set regularHours = 40 and overtimeHouse = hours-40. Then do your earnings multiplication.

Comment: Right, yep that would work. Rather than trying to do my multiplication inside the variable. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply work out how many overtime hours they have worked, and then subtract it from your basic rate hours:

```js
let hours         = prompt('Enter your hours:'),
    overtimeHours = Math.max(0, (hours - 40)),
    baseRateHours = hours - overtimeHours;

let earnings = (baseRateHours * 12) + (overtimeHours * 18);

console.log(earnings);
```

Notice that we use `Math.max()` to prevent negative overtime hours from reducing the number of hours worked at the base rate.

Comment: If I only work 32 hours that's going to give incorrect results.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. Much more simple than I was doing it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
let hours         = prompt('Enter your hours');
let baseRateHours=40;
if(hours >baseRateHours){
let overTime= hours - baseRateHours;
let earnings= (baseRateHours*12) + (overTime*18);
}
else {
let earnings = hours*12;
}
console.log(earnings)
```

Comment: Ah! I was looking into this a bit before, so you can put a let statement inside an if @Osama?

Comment: Why not ? let is for define variable

Comment: @DonaldL You can define your variables like that inside statements but it's not necessarily best practice. The code above will throw an error since earnings is not defined in the 'else' statement. You'd be better off defining it before the if/else block and then assigning the already-defined variable.

Comment: You define the variable one time not override it inside if statement I think it is ok

Comment: @Osama Please note there is actually a difference between [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)...

Comment: If it work it provide an answer if not so it is not answer